# Cors issue with reverse proxy witn nginx for react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, webpack, cors

I have my frontend(react app) run by webpack dev server on `localhost:3000`
I am running nginx server with the following conf so that i can use ui.mydomain.com to point to `localhost:3000` so that in can use this `ui.mydomain.com` with https.

```
server {
    listen       443 http2 ssl;
    listen       [::]:443 http2 ssl;
    server_name  ui.mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/certs/mydomain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/mydomain.com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }  
}
```

my backend is hosted on `backend.mydomain.com` and is capable of handling cors.
when I open `ui.mydomain.com` I make and api call to `backend.mydomain.com`.
*https://backend.mydoamain.com/users/details*.
I get the cors error. I am a frontend guy and not able to figure out this.

> Access to fetch at 'https://backend.mydomain.com/user/details' from
> origin 'https://ui.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
> value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
> not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
> 'include'.

My fetch code:

```
const options = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        credentials: 'include',
      };
      // Fetch the user data from the JSON file
      const userResponse = await fetch('https://backend.mydomain.com/user/details',options);

      const user = await userResponse.Data.json();
```

I have tried to change my nginx conf and some webpack dev server nothing seems to work.
here is my response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 16 Dec 2022 17:48:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1l
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubdomains;
Allow: *
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 1805
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Excerpt from my webpack.config.js for dev server

```
output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/'
  },
devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```

Also kindly let me know if there are any better approach.

Comment: _I get the cors error._ Adding the error message to your question would be useful.

Comment: Access to fetch at 'https://backend.mydomain.com/user/details' from origin 'https://ui.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Comment: Edit your question to add the error message there. And read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards.

Comment: hey @jub0bs any idea ?

Comment: The section of MDN Web Docs I linked to in my previous comment explains the issue. If you want the client to be able to send credentialed requests (i.e.g requests with cookies), you need to change the server's CORS configuration to allow a specific origin (not the wildcard `*`).